# What could cause pain in one's shoulder blade and collar bone?

Tags: pain, fibromyalgia, shoulder, muscle-tremor-twitch

I have an acute irritation and pain in my shoulder blade and collar bone. It's mostly in my left ones but there is also some pain in my right ones. I am in pain when I try to sleep on either shoulder. Because of the irritation, there is a twitch in my left shoulder.

I have been diagnosed with fibromyalgia but this pain is different to the mild pain in the rest of my body. I can live with the other pain but my shoulders are making me lose sleep.

What could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

There are several theories on the cause of fibromyalgia but you have to keep in mind that these theories about the causes of myalgia are merely speculative.

One of the theories states that it may be caused by the reduced effectiveness of the body's natural endorphin painkillers and the increased presence of a chemical called "substance P." Substance P amplifies pain signals.

Another theory states that fibromyalgia is caused by biochemical changes in the body and may be related to hormonal changes or menopause. In addition, some (but not all) people with fibromyalgia have low levels of human growth hormone, which may contribute to the muscle pain.

As I said earlier, the cause of fibromyalgia is still unclear, but there are some factors that may result to fibromyalgia, which are;

Genetics. Because fibromyalgia tends to run in families, there may be certain genetic mutations that may make you more susceptible to developing the disorder.

•Infections. Some illnesses appear to trigger or aggravate fibromyalgia.

•Physical or emotional trauma. Post-traumatic stress disorder has been linked to fibromyalgia.

http://www.m.webmd.com/a-to-z-guides/fibromyalgia-causes

http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/fibromyalgia/basics/causes/con-20019243

Answer (score 1):

According to [Drug.com](https://www.drugs.com/health-guide/fibromyalgia.html), Fibromyalgia can cause pain and stiffness in the muscles and joints almost anywhere in the body, including the trunk, neck, shoulders, back and hips. People often have pain between the shoulder blades and at the bottom of the neck. Pain may be either a general soreness or a gnawing ache, and stiffness is often worst in the morning.

Fibromyalgia patients are known to have tender points and shoulder blades are among those tender points and you being diagnosed with Fibromyalgia, this could be the reason.

To overcome the pain there are some simple stretches that you can try. Found this article on [Stretches for shoulder blade pain](http://www.belmarrahealth.com/shoulder-blade-scapula-pain-causes-symptoms-treatments-and-exercises/), also has a infographic which maybe helpful.